# DjangoCMS and two-factor-auth

Tags: django, django-cms, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to use the django-two-factor-auth on djangoCMS, I saw it can be hooked to views or even [called thru request.user](http://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.0/implementing.html#custom) but I'm having bad time trying to figure out how I can actually do that given that on djangoCMS, from what I got so far, there are no views I can touch.

I looked at the [example app](http://example-two-factor-auth.herokuapp.com/) on heroku for the 2-fact-auth but it doesn't give me enough hints.

Anyone has faced this before?

Thanks